# How to multithread two divisible tasks that have to be done sequentially

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have two heavy tasks that have to be done one after the other (the second task can't start if the first is not fully completed).
These tasks can be divided in equal parts that have no interaction with each other, and that can be completed independently.

The following implementation works and is significantly faster than the single thread version. But here I create 4 threads for the first task, and then 4 new threads to start the second task.
Is it possible to make a more elegant / efficient version that don't create 8 threads in total, but only 4?

```
void func1()
{
  cout << "Executing first task" << endl;
}

void func2()
{
  cout << "Executing second task" << endl;
}


int main()
{

  // First part of the work
  std::thread worker1(&func1);
  std::thread worker2(&func1);
  std::thread worker3(&func1);
  std::thread worker4(&func1);

  worker1.join();
  worker2.join();
  worker3.join();
  worker4.join();

  // Second part of the work
  std::thread worker5(&func2);
  std::thread worker6(&func2);
  std::thread worker7(&func2);
  std::thread worker8(&func2);

  worker5.join();
  worker6.join();
  worker7.join();
  worker8.join();

}
```

Comment: Why not just execute the functions sequentially? What are you hoping to gain with multthreading in such case??

Comment: These two tasks are heavy so I seek a performance gain.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, except that is would be slightly cleaner to use for-loop to create/join the threads. Also you can use a barrier to synchronize the threads between func1 and func2, thereby making it possible to reuse the threads.

Comment: I thought there would be a better way than joining the 4 first threads, and then create 4 other threads (which takes time) to do the second part. But maybe there is no better way?

Comment: @HenriV but if they need to be executed sequentially, there won't be any performance gain. You'd need a synchronization mechanism like a mutex, or condition variable, and that just complicates everything, without any performance gain.

Comment: Currently, this implementation is about 3,5x faster than the single threaded equivalent. What have to be sequential are the two main tasks, not their subdivisions.

Comment: If you want to avoid creating new threads you will need some kind of threadpool.

Comment: I'm going to look at threadpools, thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @HenriV: "*What have to be sequential are the two main tasks, not their subdivisions.*" Then maybe your question should explain that. Your question states, "I have two tasks that have to be done sequentially" That implies that the *entire tasks* must be sequential; if there are some parts that do not need to be sequential, then you should *say that*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: you're right, I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use thread pool and barrier, something like below

```
#define NUM_THREADS 4
std::barrier barr(NUM_THREADS+1);

void func()
{
  cout << "Executing first task" << endl;
  barr.wait();
  cout << "Executing second task" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread* threads[NUM_THREADS];
  // First part of the work
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    threads[i] = new std::thread(&func);

  barr.wait();

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
    threads[i]->join();
    delete threads[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not a threadpool, you still end up creating new threads for every function you want to execute

Comment: 1. There's no reason to use `new` and pointers here, store threads by value. 2. Prefer `constexpr int num_threads = 4;` to a macro.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sven Nilsson. I have c++17 so I can't use std::barrier unfortunately.

Comment: You can use barrier from a library such as Boost https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/synchronization/barriers.html